# Differential equation 4 roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine $a,b,c \in \Bbb{R}$ such that the differential equation
$y^{(4)} + ay'' + by' + cy = 0$ admits as a solution
the function $y(x) = \cos x + \sin x + e^x + e^{-x},\, x\in \Bbb{R}$.

So until now I know that I need to transform the $y$ in $r$,
$$
r^4 + ar^2 + br + c = 0,
$$
and I know that $y(x) = e^{rx}$.  I don't know how to work with the variables, I only solved differential equation without variables. Any tips?

Thank you!

Comment: I figured out that the r are those values, but it needs to be an easier method rather than guessing.

Comment: Oh my bad, I was thinking of something else. Thank you!